# Authenticating to azure artifacts from within azure maven pipeline

Tags: maven, azure-devops

I got a build job which executes a maven goal to build my software. I want to deploy the build outputs (maven artifacts) to an azure artifacts feed. To do so, I am using the following `azure-pipelines.yaml`

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: maven3
    image: maven:3-jdk-8


container: maven3

steps:
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    goals: 'package deploy'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: true
```

I've also added the repository-section snippet to my `pom.xml`.

Unfortunately the deploy goal fails with "401", which means that the `mavenAuthenticateFeed` setting did not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I got exactly the same issue. Locally it all works but with Azure Pipelines it does not.